# Sub-additivity of a measure [sufficency of an argument]

Tags: measure-theory

I don't know why the author of the book uses induction in order to show sub-aditivity of a measure $P$. Isn't it enough to observe that $ P(\bigcup E_n)=  P(\bigcup (E_n-(E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{n-1}))) = \sum P(E_n-(E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{n-1})) \le \sum P(E_n)$ because $A \subset B$ implies $P(A) \le P(B)$?

Comment: It is sufficient indeed. I think the induction here is hidden in the equality of the first two sets in your chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that this does not appear as open, yes, this is sufficient.